# About simplifying this search tool

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a question about a simple search confirm function where the code looks in a list for some value and returns the results of the search, whether anything is found. For instance the below code prints found.

I used the variable “found” and assigned it true or false to do this, but I recalled learning somewhere which did not use another variable to achieve this and instead used a simple if and else logic. How can I incorporate an “else” and still make it work while removing the variable “found”?

```
def search_confirm_tool(arr,to_find):
    found=False
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if to_find == arr[i]:
            print("Found")
            found=True
            break
    if found!=True:
        print("Not found")


search_confirm_tool(["bob","joe","dave"],"joe")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop has an else clause:

```
def search_confirm_tool(arr,to_find):
    for x in arr:
        if to_find == x:
            print("Found")
            break
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

It will be executed when you don't `break` out of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def search_confirm_tool(arr,to_find):
    if to_find in arr:
        print("found")
    else:
        print("not found")


search_confirm_tool(["bob","joe","dave"],"joe")
```

You can do this task by using above code.

Thanks